# Mongoose never returns its promise when I try to connect to the same db using a working URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a locally hosted mongodb that I can connect to using mongodb.MongoClient.

**Working code:**

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

...

```
var startApp = function(db) {
    // Get our collections in an easy to use format
    var database = {
        chats: db.collection('chats'),
        messages: db.collection('messages')
    };

    // Configure our routes
    require('./app/routes')(app, database);

    // START APP

    // Start app on port
    app.listen(port);

    // Tell user the app is running
    console.log("App running on port " + port);

    // Expose app
    exports = module.exports = app;
}

// DATABASE

var database = null;
mongoClient.connect(config.url, function(err, returnDB) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("DB connected");
        startApp(returnDB);
    }
});
```

**Legacy code that no longer works:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

...

```
// Connect to DB
console.log('Connect to database (' + db.url + ')');
mongoose.connect(db.url);
```

I have added a callback to this connect method but it never gets called (error or no error, this connect function never gets to my callback).

This entire legacy app relies on the API using mongoose to talk to the database so I do not want to redo it all using mongodb. How can I fix this?

*config.url and db.url are loaded from the same file and it is a valid and running mongodb.

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: npm -v mongoose: 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

It was really easy to fix. Thanks @Bhavik for asking me what version I was using.

I updated mongoose to 4.8.1 by specifying the newest version in packages.json and the issue is resolved.